# How to restart a dag when it fails on airflow 1.8?

Tags: restart, airflow

With:

```
default_args = {
    ...
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta (seconds = 1),
    ...
}
```

I can get the task that fails to retry several times, but how can I get it when a task fails, the DAG starts again?

Of course, automatically...

Comment: I'm curious: What would be a use case that when a task fails the whole DAG should be restarted?

Comment: You should really write each of your tasks as idempotent units of work (if you can) that way you wouldn't have to restart the DAG but instead restart only the task that failed and all downstream tasks will continue.

Comment: I have a corrupt data problem, random I have several tasks that can fail because of that. If the process starts again, the data comes clean.

Comment: Do you want the DAG to start running again only for the failed tasks or the entire DAG run for all tasks?

Comment: We have a case like this where we start an EMR cluster and submit a jobflow using the emr_create_job_flow_operator. That succeeds as long as the cluster is created successfully. To check success of the jobflow, you need to use the emr_job_flow_sensor. 

Because clusters are transient, they shut down on failure. So the failure of the sensor actually requires the create_job_flow_operator to be triggered again even though it succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical solution to this in Airflow is to create a subdagoperator that wraps all the other tasks in the dag, and apply the retry to that.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a second "Fail Check" DAG that queries for any task instances where the `task_id` matches what you want and the state is `failed` using the [`provide_session`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/db.py#L53) util. Then, you'll want to optionally clear downstream tasks as well and set the state of the relevant `DagRun` to `running`.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import and_
import json

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import TaskInstance, DagRun
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


default_args = {'start_date': datetime(2018, 6, 11),
                'retries': 2,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
                'email': [],
                'email_on_failure': True}


dag = DAG('__RESET__FAILED_TASKS',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='@daily',
          catchup=False
          )


@provide_session
def check_py(session=None, **kwargs):

    relevant_task_id = 'relevant_task_id'

    obj = (session
           .query(TaskInstance)
           .filter(and_(TaskInstance.task_id == relevant_task_id,
                        TaskInstance.state == 'failed'))
           .all())

    if obj is None:
        raise KeyError('No failed Task Instances of {} exist.'.format(relevant_task_id))
    else:
        # Clear the relevant tasks.
        (session
         .query(TaskInstance)
         .filter(and_(TaskInstance.task_id == relevant_task_id,
                      TaskInstance.state == 'failed'))
         .delete())

        # Clear downstream tasks and set relevant DAG state to RUNNING
        for _ in obj:
            _ = json.loads(_.val)

            # OPTIONAL: Clear downstream tasks in the specified Dag Run.
            for task in _['downstream_tasks']:
                (session
                 .query(TaskInstance)
                 .filter(and_(TaskInstance.task_id == task,
                              TaskInstance.dag_id == _['dag_id'],
                              TaskInstance.execution_date == datetime.strptime(_['ts'],
                                                                                "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")))
                 .delete())

            # Set the Dag Run state to "running"
            dag_run = (session
                       .query(DagRun)
                       .filter(and_(DagRun.dag_id == _['dag_id'],
                                    DagRun.execution_date == datetime.strptime(_['ts'],
                                                                               "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")))
                       .first())

            dag_run.set_state('running')

with dag:

    run_check = PythonOperator(task_id='run_check',
                               python_callable=check_py,
                               provide_context=True)

    run_check
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was attempting to fail a past DagRun based on some logic, and without the @provide_session and dag_run = (session.query(DagRun)) nothing was updating! it seemed to be just updating my local state and not the airflow DB

Comment: @Siro have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: what an ornery tool

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the `on_failure_callback` feature to call a python / bash script that would restart the DAG. There is not currently a feature provided by Airflow to automatically restart the DAG upon task failure.