# Retry a different task in a dag

Tags: python, airflow

I have an airflow DAG that looks like this

```
(A1 -> B1) -> C1 -> D1
(A2 -> B2) -> C2 -> D2
(A3 -> B3) -> C3 -> D3
```

The problem is:

- `A` always succeeds (it kicks off a get API request)
- `B` may fail (polls the API every 30 seconds until complete).
- I want to retry `A` if `B` fails.

What is the best way to do that?

I tried branching back to A, e.g.

- `A >> B >> branch >> C >> D`
- `branch >> if_failed >> A`

But I get the error `Cycle detected in DAG`

Comment: can you tell which type of operators are `A` and `B`? How you pass the data from `A` to `B`? My best guess it to unify `A` and `B`, but it depends on what are you using.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple parts of this question that we should consider:

1. When B fails, why would we want to restart A? Is it because B modifies something when it fails? In that case, wouldn't it make more sense to write the new data somewhere else instead of overwriting?
2. In the case the output of A influences whether B succeeds, we should verify the output of task A, inside task A itself.
3. If it really is the case that A needs to be re-done when B fails and we can't prevent this, then it would be best to unify the two. You have two ways of doing this:

A. You can create a custom operator that upon `execute()` calls `A`
first and then `B`.

B. You can create a PythonOperator instance and use Airflow hooks or pure python code to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

DAG is for "Directed Acyclic Graph", the important part is "Acyclic", you can't perform a cycle, your only option is to relaunch DAG when it fails. Or only one task if you can isolate it and made it idempotent.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796596/how-to-restart-a-dag-when-it-fails-on-airflow-1-8) may help you

Comment: I've updated my question to show why I can't use the solution in the answer because it will kick off the other dags (e.g. A2, and A3, when A1 fails).